# In OSX, change application name from "python"

Tags: python, macos, qt

I am working on [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/), and I am getting this nit where in OSX (10.6.5), the menubar name is 'Python' instead of orange.  It's a python/qt app.  What do I need to change?

To clarify:

- qt app, not a cli, not running in terminal.

my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>YOORANGE</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>Orange</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string>orange.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>si.ailab.Orange</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>Orange</string>
        <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
        <string>Orange, component-based data mining software</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>Orng</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1.0.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>ows</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                        <string>Orange Canvas Schema</string>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>OWSf</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
                        <string>schema.icns</string>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                        <string>Viewer</string>
                        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
                        <true/>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the Orange startup script, modified to try to use a symlink.  Clearly something work work :)

```
#!/bin/bash

BUNDLE_DIR=`dirname $0`/../
BUNDLE_DIR=`perl -MCwd=realpath -e 'print realpath($ARGV[0])' $BUNDLE_DIR`/
FRAMEWORKS_DIR="$BUNDLE_DIR"Frameworks/

CANVAS_FILE="$FRAMEWORKS_DIR"Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/orange/OrangeCanvas/orngCanvas.    pyw

cp "$FRAMEWORKS_DIR"Python.framework/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/{Python-32,AWESOME}
PYTHONEXECUTABLE="$FRAMEWORKS_DIR"Python.framework/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/AWESOME
PYTHONHOME="$FRAMEWORKS_DIR"Python.framework/Versions/2.6/

#DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$FRAMEWORKS_DIR"${DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH:+:$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH}
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$FRAMEWORKS_DIR":"$BUNDLE_DIR"Resources/Qt4/lib${DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH:+:$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH}

export PYTHONEXECUTABLE
export PYTHONHOME

export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$BUNDLE_DIR"Resources/openbabel/lib/:"$BUNDLE_DIR"Resources/openbabel/lib/openbabel/2.2.3/:$    DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

# LaunchServices passes the Carbon process identifier to the application with -psn paramter - we do not want it
if [[ "$1" == -psn* ]] ; then
 shift
fi

echo "$0"
echo "$PYTHONEXECUTABLE"
echo "$@"

exec -a "$0" "$PYTHONEXECUTABLE" "$CANVAS_FILE" "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a deeper Info.plist bundled in at `Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Info.plist`, that was being called.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to propose another solution.
It uses Cocoa to set the application name,
no need to fiddle with symlinks.
Run it early in your main module, before using PyQt.

```
    if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        # Set app name, if PyObjC is installed
        # Python 2 has PyObjC preinstalled
        # Python 3: pip3 install pyobjc-framework-Cocoa
        try:
            from Foundation import NSBundle
            bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
            if bundle:
                app_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
                app_info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
                if app_info:
                    app_info['CFBundleName'] = app_name
        except ImportError:
            pass
```

Comment: +1, however this only changes the application name in the menubar (next to the Apple menu). The application name in the app switcher (Command-Tab) is still 'Python'.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer- it's not trivial because you are running the python interpreter which is its own program with its own default title.

Long answer-
Python interpreter will execute a shell script on startup if you have environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP set.  You can probalby set the window title in this.

1. set an environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP with the name of a shell script to execute on start up (http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html#startup)
2. in that shell script, run settitle [title]

To get a title that changes every time you would have to do some extra environment variable stuff before launch.

Comment: in the shell script, literally [run settitle My Title] ?  That (minus brackets is the exact command?

Comment: @Gregg think so yeah.  try this- [link](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S_OSYVXMAYUC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=mac+os+x+shell+settitle&source=bl&ots=SsDo110LhU&sig=cYQ7XSD-i50AVrmHsy7XBgiPm90&hl=en&ei=egtfTavGD4Kq8AP9rLha&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=mac%20os%20x%20shell%20settitlesettitle&f=false)

Comment: Won't that only set the Terminal title, rather than an app title?

Comment: @Gregg minus the run.  if that doesn't work you can probably do it but I don't know, i'm writing this on windows 7.  the main thing is python will let you run arbitrary stuff on startup.

Comment: As the book in beer_monk's link states, you'll have to create the "settitle" script yourself. And indeed, it only sets the title for Terminal.app running Bash; it's not an answer to the question. Proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427221/how-do-i-change-my-qt-app-name-on-the-mac-os-x-system-menu

Answer (score 1):

It's a cheat, but i believe it works,

Create a sym link to the python app.

ln -s /opt/local/bin/python /opt/local/bin/orange

then call orange not python to start your script