# How do I change my Qt app name on the Mac OS X system menu?

Tags: qt

My Qt application is showing up with a rather unfriendly name on the Mac OS X menu. The name looks like **my_funky_app**.

How do I change this to something more likeable?

[image]

Comment: mainwindow->setTitle("Title");

Comment: That changes the main window title, but not the application name in the OS X system menu bar...see my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the TARGET line in your .pro file:

```
TARGET = FancyAppName
```

Comment: Awesome, solved. I might add, if you want to use spaces, stick the app name in double quotes. ;)

Comment: Is there another way to do this at runtime? See, I need to whitelabel my product and it would be great if I could swap an INI file and this menu change automatically (via code that reads the INI file, of course).

Answer (score 10):

Have an Info.plist and set the CFBundleName as your nice name.

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>FancyAppName<string>
```

Comment: For those with CMake, these properties [can be set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST.html) with `set_target_properties()`. In particular, the application/bundle name is set with `MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME`.